# Napili Community: delpoy navigation menu

Tags: community, change-set, napili, lightning-community

I'm trying to deploy my Napili community from a sandbox to another.

I've followed the steps in this guide: http://blogs.perficient.com/salesforce/2015/12/22/deploy-community-builder-templates-in-3-simple-steps/.

This procedure does not take the changes made to the Navigation Menu.

Can I move also the navigation menu between the sadboxes, or I have to add manually the menu Item to the navigation menu?

---

### Update - NavigationMenu Metadata Type (v47)

[NavigationMenu](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_navigationmenu.htm) is available as of version 47 to migrate custom navigation menus created using Community Builder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 3 of the documentation/blog post you linked:

> Step 3: Go to the Community Management console and update your
> administrative settings, topics, moderation criteria, etc. as these do
> not carry over automatically.

is outdated as of recently:

---

### Update - NavigationMenu Metadata Type (v47)

[NavigationMenu](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_navigationmenu.htm) is available as of version 47 to migrate custom navigation menus created using Community Builder.

However, the change set still does not cover everything, you will still have to modify some things manually through the builder.

Answer (score 2):

[**NavigationMenu**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_navigationmenu.htm) is available as of version 47 to migrate custom navigation menus created using Community Builder.

Went to search on how to deploy navigation menus used in communities. Hope anyone else stumbling upon this question finds this useful.